# Javascript Prototype Syntax

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is this valid Javascript syntax? What does it do?

```
Parser.prototype = {

  // ...

  get currentState() {
    return this.state[this.state.length - 1];
  },

  // ...

}
```

See https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/parser.js.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It defines a [*getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get):

> Binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

Read about [Getters and Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters).

This function is called when you access the property:

```
var sth = obj.currentState
```

Notice that it is *not* a function call (there are no `()`), but a normal property access.

A corresponding [*setter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/set_Operator) would look like this:

```
set currentState(value) {
  // do something with value
  // value would be 42 in the next example
}
```

and would be called when you assign a value to that property, e.g.

```
obj.currentState = 42;
```

The `get` and `set` keywords a special operators to be used inside the object literal notation. You could also use `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__`:

```
Parser.prototype.__defineGetter__('currentStatus', function() {
    return this.state[this.state.length - 1];
});
```

---

I'm not sure in which version it was introduced though, it might not be supported by all browsers (especially IE ;)).

Comment: It was introduced in ECMAScript 5, and IE9 was the first browser with a functional ES5 engine.